# Cross browser url parameter with utf8 possible?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, browser-support

1.May i know is all modern browsers support to user address parameter like http://abc.com?something=UTF8chactersHERE   ?

2.which browser does not support it? 

3. can javascript parse the parameter properly on all browser?

> example : http://abc.com?something=环保部&something2=环保部

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should percent-escape the UTF-8 representation of the characters:

```
http://abc.com/?something=环保部&something2=环保部
```

becomes

```
http://abc.com/?something=%E7%8E%AF%E4%BF%9D%E9%83%A8&something2=%E7%8E%AF%E4%BF%9D%E9%83%A8
```

Any modern browser will display the second as the first in the URL bar.

Comment: any browser that not able to auto convert that?